# Home directory is full. How to increase it's size?

Tags: linux, debian, diskspace

Please see the image below.

Notice that my `/home` directory is already 100% but I still got plenty of space on `/dev/mapper/vg00-srv`. Is there a way that I can use that space for my `/home` or rather increase the size of my `/home` directory. This is a Debian box.

[image: Debian server]

Your response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57410/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition-in-debian

Comment: Or alternatively if you have any unallocated space left you can always add another partition to accommodate a subdirectory from your full parition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo su -
umount /srv
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-srv 800G
lvresize -L 810G /dev/mapper/vg00-srv
lvresize -L +80G /dev/mapper/vg00-home
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-home
mount /srv
```

Comment: Wow, this works for me. Howerver my "/dev/mapper/vg00-srv" was corrupted or like. I can't do "mount /srv" anymore. This my error https://www.evernote.com/shard/s214/sh/47c7287a-9456-4e2d-8604-03986fff633d/dc273898095bdcc40d3729a25f35377c

Comment: Perhaps it is, Now I have bigger problem because I don't know how to recover the partition/directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this below line in your /var/fstab file.

`UUID=685a1898-6c19-4327-a383-1f8b840a9a3c /home           ext4    defaults`

Change ext4 to your desired home folder partition.